# Google Workspace Groups API: Get permissions with Python

Tags: python, permissions, google-workspace, group

I'm trying to get the Google group permissions like `WHO_CAN_LEAVE` for all of our Workspace groups via API in Python.

With this request I'm just able to get the group itself:
`results = service.groups().list(domain=domain, orderBy='email').execute()`. There's no permission result in it.

The official documentation says nothing about it but I know GAM Advanced is able to get the group permissions with `gam.exe print groups domain DOMAIN matchsetting whocanpostmessage anyone_can_post`.

Do you know how I could get to the solution or which HTTP request I can use?